# phpBB ACP Permissions Issue - { acl_u_title_edit } and { acl_u_title_ignore_reqs }

Tags: permissions, phpbb

So here is the deal.

I installed the MOD Installer and this mod: http://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=70&t=574342

After that I uninstalled the mod and this is what I got:
[image]

Already tried deleting all forum directory and re uploading another one from scratch, where no mods have been installed. The problem wasn't corrected.

This two: { acl_u_title_edit } and { acl_u_title_ignore_reqs } only appear in those group permissions, where I have enabled them when I had the mod. This mod basically added those, they do not appear on other group permissions, where this two options remained on "no"

The problem must be somewhere in MYSQL. Already deleted the "thanks" mod(another I had installed) from mod table in mysql.

**phpBB version: 3.0.9**

Maybe you can help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think that those permissions are doing any harm to your phpbb installation. On the contrary: if you re-installed the mod your permissions would be saved.

Answer (score 0):

> This two: { acl_u_title_edit } and { acl_u_title_ignore_reqs }

Those two belong to your language files. You'll find that the mod uses languages/en
and your language is en_us. <-(*assumption*)

Just copy the mod file from language/en/mod/info_acp_custom_title_mod.php
to language/en_us/mod/ folder or language/name_of_language_here/mod/ folder

That mod was also marked as abandoned and was made in 2007 so I am assuming it would need to be updated to comply with 3.0.9 version which may be causing MySQL errors or not work as required.